# Minimum number of mkdirs to create file architecture

Tags: java, performance, collections

Assuming I have a `List` of paths and I want to reduce it in order to have the minimal number of `file.mkdirs()` to run to recreate the whole architecture.

Thus, from :

> [/foo,/foo/bar, /foo/bar/coo, /foo/bar/coo2,/foo/barbie,/notFoo/something]

I expect :

> [/notFoo/something, /foo/barbie, /foo/bar/coo, /foo/bar/coo2]

The naive way I got to do this is :

```
List<String> l_paths = Arrays.asList("/foo","/foo/bar", "/foo/bar/coo","/foo/barbie","/notFoo/something");
    ArrayList<String> l_reducted = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> l_ordered = l_paths.stream().sorted((p1,p2) -> p2.compareTo(p1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(String l_string : l_ordered){
        if(l_reducted.stream().noneMatch(e -> e.startsWith(l_string) && e.substring(l_string.length()).contains("/"))){
            l_reducted.add(l_string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(l_reducted);
```

or, for java 8 lovers :

```
// java 8 style, way less readable IMO
    BiFunction<List<String>, String, List<String>> myAccumulator = new BiFunction<List<String>, String, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> apply(List<String> list, String string) {
            if (list.stream().noneMatch(e -> e.startsWith(string) && e.substring(string.length()).contains("/"))) {
                list.add(string);
            }
            return list;
        }
    };
    System.out.println(l_paths.stream().sorted((p1, p2) -> p2.compareTo(p1))
            .reduce(new ArrayList<>(),
                    myAccumulator, 
                    (list1, list2) -> {
                        list2.stream().forEach(i -> myAccumulator.apply(list1, i));
                        return list1;
                    }));
```

But I'm pretty convinced that splitting every path on the separator and inserting them into a tree structure similar to a file system would be way better (but I'm not proficient in trees, so I haven't implemented it) as it would then allow to just visit the nodes and mkdir my way.

What would you think is better ?

Disclaimer : I'm not really here to discuss about premature optimization, I was simply interested in the algorithm, for *intellectual curiosity*. But let's say the mkdir is actually a call to a really slow web service (that doesn't even understand mkdirs on a whole path) and that the number of calls matters. And we're also gonna assume that I have millions of paths in my collection and that the computational complexity of the reduction also matters.

Comment: Have you profiled it to see if your program is faster than simply calling `mkdirs()` for each path?

Comment: @SteveSmith I haven't, as it is not an actual production bottleneck, it's just that I encountered the issue several times and never cared. Today I decided "and what if I cared, for once?". What would be the way to do such thing if that was important ? How do I properly reduce my list with a test that iterates over the list ? I added a disclaimer to my question (but I thought I could get away with that question without it)

Comment: I don't have time nor budget to run benchmark to optimize something that isn't a bottleneck. But if there was an elegant (as short and readable) way to reduce the list that is significantly better than just mkdirs everything, I would be glad to discover it.

Comment: Before you consider efficiency or conciseness, you need to achieve *correctness*.  Try your current method on input consisting of just the paths `/foo` and `/foo2`.

Comment: `sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())` equals `sorted((p1, p2) -> p2.compareTo(p1))`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh yes, I overlooked that, i will correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Treating this as an academic exercise, rather than agreeing that reducing calls to `mkdirs()` is a worthwhile pursuit...

1. Sort the list alphabetically
2. Map each string to a `String[]` with `path.split("/")`
3. Iterate through the list. If the current entry does not begin with all the elements of the previous entry, output the previous entry.
4. Finally output the last entry seen (assumes the input list is not empty)

Something like:

```
 List<String[]> sortedPaths = paths.stream().sorted().map( s -> s.split("/"))

 List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
 String[] previous = new String[0];

 for(String[] path : sortedPaths) {
     if(! beginsWith(path,previous)) {
          out.add(String.join(",", previous));
     }
     previous = path;
 }
 out.add(String.join(",", previous));
```

I leave the implementation of `beginsWith(String[], String[])` to the reader, as well as dealing with an empty input list if you need to.

---

Alternatively, still sorting alphabetically first:

```
  for(String path : paths) {
      if(out.isEmpty() || ! isSubPath(out.get(out.size()-1), path) {
          out.add(path);
      } else {
          out.set(out.size()-1, path);
      }
  }
```

(`isSubPath` tests whether the first argument has the same parent dirs as the second)

---

Note that if you're trying to save on filesystem calls:

```
 mkdirs("/a/b/c/d");
 mkdirs("/a/b/e/f");
```

... is still doing more system calls than strictly necessary, because behind `mkdirs()` is a bunch of `mkdir()`, and it's going to try to create `/a` and `/a/b` twice.

If you were fanatical about reducing filesystem operations (and this could be worthwhile, for example on a slow link to a remote service) you would want to:

- expand your list of paths to a list of individual `mkdir()`s -- that is, `{"a/b/c"}` becomes `{"a", "a/b", "a/b/c"}`
- sort and remove duplicates
- `mkdir()` for each one.

Comment: Upvoter here. Could not understand what you mean by "the previous entry does not start with the same elements as the current one" and that is why I added my own answer. But I am sure your answer gave me some hints.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz will clarify

Comment: "start with the same elements" is not enough in my opinion. Could be: `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/d`. They both start with `/a/b`, but there is no "is a subdirectory of" relation between them. Your idea is right, its wording not.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz yep, I see. I think it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm pretty convinced that splitting every path on the separator
>   and inserting them into a tree structure similar to a file system
>   would be way better (but I'm not proficient in trees, so I haven't
>   implemented it) as it would then allow to just visit the nodes and
>   mkdir my way.

You certainly could use a Trie-like tree-based data structure to approach the problem, with each node corresponding to one path segment.  If you record all the paths in such a data structure, then you can find the minimal set needed to cause the whole hierarchy to be created -- it is exactly those that correspond to leaf nodes.

But it would be rather a lot of work to write the code for the data structure.  Only if you had some continuing use for it would that make any sense to me.  If all you need to do is identify the leaf nodes of the (hypothetical) trie, you can do it pretty cleanly and efficiently by the approach @slim suggests.